# Use a SMB Drive as an apache directory

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, mount, smbfs

Want to store some data got with an apache server in a NAS mounted as a SMB Share.

I've mounted it with /etc/fstab and wheb i want to put some file as apache user, everything is working.

But when some file is got and have to be stored (in a WordPress website), i got an error, and the file won't be stored, even with à directory mask of 0777.

How can i make this working ?

Comment: What's the error? & can you paste the list permissions for that directory here? command is ls -ld DIRECTORY

Comment: Can't get this for now, everithing is on m'y work server, i Will update tomorrow in m'y morning (living un France) Can you please come back when i'll comment this post again ?

Comment: Sure. I'll have a look